# Blasphemous 2 The Ultimate Sword Excalibur

Tags: blasphemous-2

I've been playing Blasphemous 2 and it's a great game! I suddenly watched a video on a social media platform that there is a Excalibur sword in the game which can oneshot game boss fights, I searched it through and found no instructions about getting this holy sword!

Can someone help me with this? I'm kinda interested at getting this sword not only for boss-fight purposes but also for collectibles.

Comment: Care to share either a link to said video or a screenshot of that character using the sword? Right now, not only I can't find any reference to any other weapon in the game other that the 3 starting ones, I can't even find anyone but you mentioning an Excalibur being in the game, and that doesn't look well for this post as you may understand...